# If $\Delta O \pmod {2^n} = (2)$ in $\Bbb{Z}/2^n$ for all $n \geq 1$, then does $\Delta O = (2)$ in $\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, open-problem

Let $O = $ the set of odd primes in $\Bbb{N}$. And $M = \Delta O = \{ x-y: x,y \in O\}$.  Then we can take either set $X$ modulo $n$ for any $n \geq 2$: $\overline{X} = \{ x + (n) : x \in X\}$.

Then we have that $\overline{M} = \overline{\Delta O} = \Delta\overline{O}$ i.e. moduloing a set commutes with differencing.

There is a major open problem which is that $M = (2)$ the ideal generated by $2$ in $\Bbb{Z}$.  That is to say for every integer $z \in \Bbb{Z}$ there exists an odd prime solution to $p - q = 2z$.

**My question is:** if it can be proven that $\overline{M} = (2)$ in every ring $\Bbb{Z}/2^n$ then does it follow that $M = (2)$ in $\Bbb{Z}$?  That is to say, given a proof of that lemma, could the open problem be closed?

Can we make use of the fact that $f_n : \Bbb{Z}/(2^{n}) \twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{Z}/(2^{n-1})$ (ring homomorphism) for all $n \geq 2$?

That would give us an inverse system in the category of rings and the $2$-adic integer ring $\widehat{\Bbb{Z}_2} = \lim\limits_{\leftarrow} \Bbb{Z}/(2^i)$, the categorical limit.  For which we know that there is an injection of rings:

$$
g : \Bbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \widehat{\Bbb{Z}_2}.
$$

---

Let $(2)_{n}$ be the ideal $2 \Bbb{Z}/2^{n}$.  Then given $f_n : \Bbb{Z}/2^n \twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{Z}/2^{n-1}$ for all $n \geq 2$ we have:

$$
f_n((2)_n) = 2 f_n(\Bbb{Z}/2^n) = 2\Bbb{Z}/2^{n-1} = (2)_{n-1}
$$

So we have a commutative sequence of commutative squares in the category of rings:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@>{...}>> (2)_n @>{g_n}>> (2)_{n-1} @>{...}>> \\
 ...@V{i}VV @V{j}VV ... \\
@>{...}>> \Bbb{Z}/2^n @>{f_n}>> \Bbb{Z}/2^{n-1}  @>{...}>> \\
\end{CD}
$$

where $i,j$ are inclusions and $g_n$ is the restriction of $f_n$ to $(2)_n$ is a surjective homomorphism of rings (every ideal is also a subring).

I worked out some of the math in a related question:

[Limit of ideals modulo $p^n$ isomorphic to an ideal of the ring of $p$-adic integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799744/limit-of-ideals-modulo-pn-isomorphic-to-an-ideal-of-the-ring-of-p-adic-inte)

Comment: $M_2$ is the odd primes less than four, so how does it contain five and seven?

Comment: @GerryMyerson fixed

Comment: Not really. What is five doing in $M_2$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson k thanks.  Now really fixed ;)

Comment: @GerryMyerson I haven't proved that is holds for all $n \geq 2$.  I'm just looking ahead seeing if it even matters if you prove that it does.  If you prove that it holds for all $n\geq 2$, then can we complete the proof of $2 \Bbb{Z} = \Delta O$ or is this a bad approach is the question.

Comment: Now in your definition of $\overline{M_n}$, does $(2^{n-1})$ mean the ideal generated by $2^{n-1}$? If so, shouldn't it be $(2^n)$?

Comment: If you use $2^n$, then for example $\overline{\Delta(M_3)}= \Delta\{3,5,7\} \pmod{8} = \{0, 2, 4\} = (2)\Bbb{Z}/(8) \setminus \{6\}$ i.e. it's not the full list.  Why not have it be full by what I have written?  It shouldn't matter limit-wise intuitively speaking.  If you have to have it be $2^n$ on the nose, then you run into more troublesome math.  That it's always appearing to be $(2)$ and $(2)$ appears in what we aim to prove is a good sign in my oppinion.  Good question though :)

Comment: Actually, you have defined $\overline{M_n}$, but you never defined $\overline{\Delta(M_n)}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks, I've taken out $\overline{M_n}$ definition and replaced with $\overline{\Delta(M_n)}$

Comment: Are you asking (could be me but it's hard to tell): If $I \subset \mathbb{Z}_2$ is such that $\pi_n(I) = (\overline{2})$, where $\pi_n: \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ are the projections, then is $I \cap g(\mathbb{Z}) = (2) \subset \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @SBRJCT addressed your question, see rewrite.  Dispensed with union of subsets and just take $M$ to be the set of all odd prime first differences.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's easy to find a set $M$ of integers which isn't the ideal generated by $2$ in the integers but which does reduce, for every $n$, to the ideal generated by $2$ in the integers modulo $2^n$. For example, $M=\{\,2,4,6,8,10,12,\dots\,\}$. Or $M=\{\,2,100,1000,10006,100000,\dots\,\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify $\mathbb{Z}$ with its image in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then if an ideal $J \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ satisfies $J \cap \mathbb{Z} = p\mathbb{Z}$, you must have $J \supset (p\mathbb{Z})\mathbb{Z}_p$ (the extended ideal). But $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a DVR with max ideal $(p\mathbb{Z})\mathbb{Z}_p$, whence $J = (p\mathbb{Z})\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Furthermore, if an ideal $M \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ is such that $\pi_n(M) = (p+\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$ for all $n \geq 1$ in $\mathbb{N}$, then $M$ contains the limit of the inverse system defined by those ideals (which is a sub-inverse system to that defining $\mathbb{Z}_p$) which is exactly the maximal ideal $(p\mathbb{Z})\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Edit: As per Gerry's comment, this isn't enough to close out the conjecture; you'd have to also know that $M$ is actually an ideal.